# Kafka Connect won't pick up custom connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, openedge

I am trying to use kafka connect in a docker container with a custom connector (PROGRESS_DATADIRECT_JDBC_OE_ALL.jar) to connect to an openedge database.

I have put the JAR file in the plugin path (usr/share/java) but it won't load as a connector.

```
COPY Openedge/PROGRESS_DATADIRECT_JDBC_OE_ALL.jar /usr/share/java/progress
```

I can load another (standard) connector by putting it in the plugin path. This works

```
COPY confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.3.2 /usr/share/java/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.3.2
```

A little lost on how to move forward and I'm very new to kafka. My main sources of information are
[openedge to kafka streaming](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/streaming-your-data-from-openedge-to-kafka) and [How to use Kafka connect](https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/self-managed/userguide.html#installing-kconnect-plugins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC Drivers are not Connect plugins, nor are they connectors themselves.

You'd need to set the JVM `CLASSPATH` environment variable for detecting JDBC Drivers, as with any Java process.

The instructions on the linked site suggest you should copy the JDBC Drivers into the directory for the existing Confluent JDBC connector. While you could use a Docker `COPY` command, the better way would be to use `confluent-hub install`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
My setup is a kafka-connect image, extended very little. Other kafka services are combined in a docker-compose.yml file.

I have tried to set the classpath by
• Changing CLASSPATH in docker-compose.yml. Current value is “/usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.0.1.jar” and I have tried adding the jar to this classpath as well as changing current setting to the monitoring-interceptors folder and putting the jar there
• I have also tried to add “ENV CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/progress_datadirect_jdbc_oe_all.jar” to the dockerfile.

Comment: My tested changes result in “invalid connector class” when I try to test the connector by adding a config file in Kafka Connect Control Center.
I am obviously not finding the right way to set the classpath here. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: "Invalid connector" refers to JDBC connector, not the classpath. As mentioned, why aren't you just adding the jdbc driver to the existing jdbc connector folder next to its own Postgres and sqlite driver jars?

Answer (score 1):

@OneCricketeer had the solution. As a retro for me and hopefully helpful to someone else, here are my steps to make this work.
Copy the JDBC Connector to CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH and install with confluent hub install:

```
COPY confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.3.2.zip /usr/share/java
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt /usr/share/java/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.3.2.zip
```

Copy the driver (I ended up using openedge.jar) to the path where other jars are located (like sqllite) according to @OneCricketeer suggestion.

```
COPY Openedge/openedge.jar /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/lib
```

Verify with this by enabling [DEBUG](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/logging.html#using-environment-variables-docker) as suggested by this [page](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#no-suitable-driver-found)
Finally add a .properties file to create the connector. In my case based on the one in “openedge to kafka streaming” link above